# How to return a list of specific type instead of List<Object[]> in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, hql

I have tree of classes:

```
classA {  
      classB b;  
      classC c;
      .....
}
```

I have HQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, c.field4
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.fk
       LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.id = c.fk
```

This query returns `List<Object[]>`.

Is it possible to cast the returned data to the following class:

```
classD {
    Type1 fiedl1;
    Type2 field2;
    Type3 field3;
}
```

So can casting be made by Hibernate or I need manually do all casting?

Comment: `select a from a left outer join b on   a.id=b.fk left outer join c on b.id=c.fk` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No. query returns List<Object[]>, but I would like that query returns List<classD>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361558/java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are different types of selects in JPA queries. **You are currently using Array as a return type, what you need is Construct return type.** Here is how to achieve this:

```
String queryStr =
    "select NEW package.YourDefinedCustomClass(
     a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, c.field4) from a left outer join b 
     on a.id=b.fk left outer join c on b.id=c.fk";

TypedQuery<YourDefinedCustomClass> query =
    em.createQuery(queryStr, YourDefinedCustomClass.class);

List<YourDefinedCustomClass> results = query.getResultList();
```

**Basically there are two things:**

1. Custom class must be your results return type
2. Custom class must have a constructor which takes result values you define in query string.

[Read more on selects in JPA2 queries.](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_in_Criteria_Queries_)

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer! Just to make the answer even more accurate I'd like to point out that the constructor name must be fully qualified, and [reserved words in your package name can lead to problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891824).

Comment: I'm using Shared Session Contract, so I don't have the `entityManager` object. Anyway to workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure you can do type casts.

```
 List<classD> newlist = ...;
 for(Object o : list){
      newlist.add((classD) o);
 }
```

Be careful with this though

So yes. Manual casting. (note: with arrays (you can directly cast) )

Comment: Isnt list is type of List<Object[]>? I do not get it, your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TypedQuery

```
TypedQuery<ClassA> q = em.createQuery("select a from a left outer join b on a.id=b.fk left outer join c on b.id=c.fk", ClassA.class); 
List<ClassA> res = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: This kind of return type works only for single value selects. JPA documentation says: `The select list of the query must contain only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by the resultClass argument`. And hibernate sources say `"Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [" + resultClass.getName() + "]"`. So basically it will throw IllegalArgumentException - if the query string is found to be invalid or if the query result is found to not be assignable to the specified type

Answer (score 1):

If you use Hibernate 5.x, you can use a `ResultTransformer`, as, e.g., described [in this blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/). Note that `ResultTransformer` will be @Deprecated in Hibernate 6.

Applied to your scenario:

```
List<classD> classDDTOs = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, c.field4 " +
    "FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.fk " +
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.id = c.fk")
.unwrap( org.hibernate.query.Query.class )
.setResultTransformer( 
    new ResultTransformer() {
        @Override
        public Object transformTuple(
            Object[] tuple, 
            String[] aliases) {
            return new classD(
                (Type1) tuple[0],
                (Type2) tuple[1],
                (Type3) tuple[1],
            );
        }

        @Override
        public List transformList(List collection) {
            return collection;
        }
    } 
)
.getResultList();
```

The above code assumes `classD` has a constructor `classD(Type1, Type2, Type3)`.

An advantage of this approach is that it lets you define the `ResultTransformer` once and allows you to reuse it in all queries with the same result type.

Comment: Wow I am going to have to try this, but would the new way with hibernate 6

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem..i wrote this query

```
Query sqlquery = session.createQuery("select c.courseName,f.facultyID,f.facultyName,f.facultyEmailID,f.facultyContactNo,s.subjectName from com.bean.CourseBean as c,com.bean.FacultyBean as f,com.bean.Faculty_SubjectBean as fs,com.bean.SubjectBean as s where f.facultyID=fs.facultyBean.facultyID AND s.subjectID=fs.subjectBean.subjectID AND c.courseID=f.courseBean.courseID AND collegeid=1");
```

and i returned list of object and in servlet i wrote,

java.util.List objList= objFacultyService.listFaculty_sql(1);

```
java.util.List<Temp> objtemp = new ArrayList<Temp>() ;
for (Object[] objects : objList)
{


        Temp temp = new Temp();
        temp.setFacultyEmailID(objects[3].toString());
        temp.setCourseName(objects[0].toString());
        if(objects[4]==null)
        {
            temp.setFacultyContactNo(1);
        }
        else
        {
                  temp.setFacultyContactNo(Long.parseLong(objects[4].toString()));
        }
        temp.setFacultyID(Long.parseLong(objects[1].toString()));
        temp.setFacultyName(objects[2].toString());
        temp.setSubjectName(objects[5].toString());
        objtemp.add(temp);




}
```