# How to write sql innerquery in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, arraylist

presently my method uses basic jdbc concept like this,

```
public static ArrayList<VehicleDetailsBean>
   getAllVehicleDetails(String groupId,String clientId) 
                 throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

ArrayList<VehicleDetailsBean> vehicleDetailsList =
   new ArrayList<VehicleDetailsBean>(); 
try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String  sql ="SELECT a.vehicleno,a.lat,a.lng,a.status, "+
        "a.rdate,a.rtime from latlng a,vehicle_details b where"+ 
        "a.vehicleno=b.vehicleno and b.clientid='"+
        clientId+"'  and b.groupid in(select groupid from group_details"+
        " where groupname='"+groupId+"' and clientid='"+clientId+"')";

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {  
            VehicleDetailsBean vehicleDetailsBean=new VehicleDetailsBean();
            vehicleDetailsBean.setVehicleno(rs.getString("vehicleno"));
            vehicleDetailsBean.setLat(rs.getString("lat"));
            vehicleDetailsBean.setLng(rs.getString("lng"));
            vehicleDetailsBean.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));
            vehicleDetailsBean.setRdate(rs.getInt("rdate"));
            vehicleDetailsBean.setRtime(rs.getString("rtime"));
            vehicleDetailsList.add(vehicleDetailsBean);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it returns an `ArrayList`. Now I want to change it to hibernate SO I will change above code as,

```
  query = session.createQuery(hqlquery);//I am not getting how to write hqlquery
    List<Object[]> groupList = query.list();
    for(Object[] arr : groupList){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

by doing this it returns `List` object but my method has to return `ArrayList`. So can any one help me to write query and return the result as `ArrayList`.

Comment: start with `FROM ...` , use the class name in place of table name and class attributes in place of the column names.

Comment: k . . but how to make it ArrayList

Comment: @Raghu does [this](http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2012/12/hql-and-nested-queries.html) help you

Comment: `query.list()` should return a `List` of array of `Object`.

Comment: @ankur-singhal can't we put in `ArrayList`

Comment: Convert that `List` to a `new ArrayList` or `addAll()` that `List` to an `ArrayList` !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return it as ArrayList, you can just addAll it with your ArrayList.

```
List<VehicleDetailsBean> groupList = (List<VehicleDetailsBean>) query.list();
vehicleDetailsList.addAll(groupList);
return vehicleDetailsList;
```

You can see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829197/how-to-return-object-type-instead-of-listobject-in-hibernate) and [a way to cast here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913150/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-hibernate-query-list-to-listtype)

**EDIT**

Or try to add [entity](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17313)

```
List<LatitudeBean> bean = (List<LatitudeBean>) session.createSQLQuery(query)
.addEntity(LatitudeBean.class).list();
//add to ArrayList here
```

Comment: Hello Query is executing but error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.abc.its.beans.LatitudeBean`

Comment: it returns LatitudeBean so change the VehicleDetailsBean to LatitudeBean

Comment: No no, it has to be `LatitudeBean`. So I have `List<LatitudeBean> groupList = (List<LatitudeBean>) query.list();` . It showing the above exceptional msg.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the ugly way:

```java
query = session.createQuery(hqlquery); // Take a walk in Hibernate Docs for HQL Queries
List<?> groupList = query.list();
ArrayList<VehicleDetailsBean> result = new ArrayList<VehicleDetailsBean>(groupList.size());
for (Object o : groupList) {
  result.add((VehicleDetailsBean) o);
}
return result;
```