# SQL aggregation GROUP BY and COUNT in Spring JPA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

I have an SQL table:

```
@Table(name = "population_table")
public class Population {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String country;
  private String state;
  private String area;
  private String population;
}
```

I want to get a count, grouping by country and state with the output class being List of Count:

```
  private static class Count {
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private long count;
  }
```

I know the query is

```
SELECT country, state, Count(*)
FROM population_table
GROUP BY country, state
```

But I want to do this using JPA Specification. How can I achieve this using JPA Specification in spring boot?

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to do this using Specifications" ?

Comment: @NitishKumar I mean JPA specification

Comment: This will help [Returning Specific type using DTO Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829197/how-to-return-a-list-of-specific-type-instead-of-listobject-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could achieve this by using [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) in Spring Data JPA.

Create a custom `Repository` method like

```
@Repository
public interface PopulationRepository extends JpaRepository<Population, Long> {

@Query("select new com.example.Count(country, state, count(p) )
       from Population p
       group by p.country, p.state")
public List<Count> getCountByCountryAndState();

}
```

Also you must define the specific constructor in `Count` class which will handle this projection

```
private static class Count {
 private String country;
 private String state;
 private long count;
 
 //This constructor will be used by Spring Data JPA 
 //for creating this class instances as per result set
 public Count(String country,String state, long count){
   this.country = country;
   this.state = state;
   this.count = count;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JpaRepository interface.
Example:

```
@Repository
public interface PopulationRepository extends JpaRepository<Population, Long> {

    public int countAllByCountryAndState(String countryName, String stateName);

}
```

And in your service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PopulationService {

    @Autowired
    private PopulationRepository populationRepository;

    public int countPopulationByCountryAndState(String countryName, String stateName) { 

         return populationRepository.countAllByCountryAndState(countryName, stateName);
    }

}
```

Sorry, I made mistake it can be simpler. I edited my code.

Comment: Your code returns one count for specific inputs (name and state). I understand OP wants a list of count group by name and state